# how to split a string with | but not with \\|

Tags: java, regex

I have a string as following

```
"value1|value2,value3|value4\\|value5"
```

I need to split this string into parts by | character. But If the escape is passed before the | (as \|) then i dont want to split it by there. Is there a simple regex which this can be done.

Comment: What about `\\|` :P?

Comment: What @HamZa said. Is `value3|value4\\|value5` possible? For instance `http:\\\\server.com\\|foo`?

Comment: @TheLostMind your probably changed too much. I suspect that earlier version was not about String but test it represents. Now all comments and answers here kind of loose their point.

Comment: @Pshemo - I looked at 2 things before changing. 1. Tag (Java). Code won't compile in java unless you use `\\|`. 2. OP's question title.

Comment: @TheLostMind OK but confusing part stays and now comments asking about `\\|` case would need to be rewritten as `\\\\|`. In other words what if OP will have even number of ``\`` before `|`. Should we split on such `|` or not? In other words will ``\`` also escape ``\``?

Comment: @Pshemo - I kinda agree with you. Unfortunately I am as helpless as you :P. I can revert this question to its original state but that won't do any good as the *accepted* answer backs my edit :)

Comment: Accepted answer is OK if we will not have any `\\\\|` case. Fortunately Jerry posted correct approach which will be able to handle more advanced scenario (accept only non `|` ``\`` characters OR accept any characters escaped with ``\``).

Comment: @Pshemo Then I guess we should remove our comments?

Comment: @HamZa I don't know about that. Leaving them could give a hint that accepted answer may not be perfect for all cases. Until OP [edit] this question and clarifies things I would leave it as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a negative lookbehind assertion.

```
"(?<!\\\\)\\|"
```

Use four backslashes in your regex to match a single backslash character.

**Example:**

```
String s = "value1|value2,value3|value4\\|value5";
String parts[] = s.split("(?<!\\\\)\\|");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output:

```
[value1, value2,value3, value4\|value5]
```

Comment: Just a warning to anyone reading this. Splitting is **not the appropriate approach** when dealing with delimited text which allows the delimiter to be escaped and specified in the fields. It is not a reliable way to parse this string `field\\\|one\\|field\|two|field3\\|field4` for example.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably match all instead of trying to split:

```
(?:[^|\\\\]+|\\\\.)+
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/oF3oF1/1)

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/nYRnEL)

Comment: This is the better method, but it can't detect empty field.